# Multiple IFs won't work

Tags: c#, windows, if-statement, console-application, console.readline

I'm creating a Desktop application (console) for Windows, using C#.

This is my code:

```
namespace myapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to exit!");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (line == "exit") {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (line == "copyright") {
                Console.WriteLine("Copyright 2017 TIVJ-dev");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I type "exit", it works fine (I'm sure it does this `Environment.Exit(0);` action). But if I type "copyright", it does not work. I can see an empty line instead. I started with C# today, so my apologies if this is very beginner problem. I haven't found solution on the internet.

Screenshot:

[image: Copyright command is not doing anything]

Comment: change it to `if (line.Tolower() == "copyright")`

Comment: Have you tried using a `Console.WriteLine()` for the "exit", as well, to see if it works as expected?

Comment: also trim it before comparing like `if (line.Trim() == "copyright")`

Comment: running your program works as expected. It does output copyright, but you probably won't see it because the program finishes.

Comment: What @Riv said makes perfect sense, actually.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? There's nothing I can see that's wrong with your code - you should learn to use the debugger for something as simple as this.

Comment: He told _There comes only empty line_. Program should be finished as expected, I think that is the problem. Why the program is still running. @Riv

Comment: @Matt Jones: I haqven't yet maked any versions. Just trying to get two IFs work, BY DEBUGGING!

Comment: @Kuvaaja - I have no idea what you mean. Put a breakpoint in and step through it to see a) what the value of `line` is and b) whether the code executes the second `if` statement. No idea what "maked any versions" even means, and I think your caps lock is stuck.

Comment: I've run this code and it works exactly as you have said it should work. Whatever issue you have, it's not in the code.

Comment: @Tom. You published answer ´, but it's deleted. I can't mark it as solution. So the solution is else if.

Comment: It is not relevant with else if.

Comment: Else if IS really the answer!

Comment: @Kuvaaja no it isn't. Your code in the question works. Whatever issue you have, it's not code related.

Comment: Agree with @MattJones, your code does work

Comment: If this makes sense I can delete this question. What do you think?

Comment: Rebuild might be the real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an else if statement;

```
   namespace myapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to exit!");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (line == "exit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (line == "copyright") {
                Console.WriteLine("Copyright 2017 TIVJ-dev");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

By using an `if/else` this does the same as using multiple `if` statements however this is a more efficient way and make it easier when using break points.

Comment: What difference does this make at all to the original code? The original code **worked**.

Comment: Can people please advise why this answer is being down voted? else if is a vaild way of checking?

Comment: @Tom not the downvoter, but I assume it was because the original code is fine and should work, the OP had/has another issue completely. Your addition doesn't change anything for this example

Comment: @Tom if/else probably more efficient, but aside from that it does the same thing as OP's original code. Can't see how it would solve the problem

Comment: @Kuvaaja I don't know how many more times I can say this, but the problem is not in your code. Your original code worked. Considering that the first if statement would **terminate the process** I don't see how an `else if` can be considered to be any better.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure in what way it doesn't work. It should run

```
Console.WriteLine("Copyright 2017 TIVJ-dev");
```

then immediately close the console window. Try putting another

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end of Main().

Comment: Works for me. Sorry. In what way is it "not working"? What actually happens?

Comment: @Kuvaaja, it is back sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the application by pressing ctrl F5 in visual studio and seeing if it works. Alternatively click on debug->start without debugging.

Then write "copyright" and press enter.

What is probably happening is that the console is printing the line, then closing before you have a chance to see it. When you don't use the debugger the console stays open even once the application is finished.

Answer (score -1):

Now everyone: Now this project works fine! Thanks for people who said add another Console.ReadLine. When I tested else if, I forgot there was that also. But now it works, so I try to close this. Thanks everyone!